# Откуда берется пустая картинка при запросе из БД?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Новость взята случайная!) Пытаюсь создать простенький сайт на PHP для новостей с запросами данных из БД. Но при вызове новости вначале откуда-то берется пустая картинка. Как исправить? Или может написать код,  который не будет допускать пустые данные?
`

```
<?php require "blocks/header.php"?> <!-- вызывает заголовок -->
  <?php
     $host = 'localhost'; //имя хоста, на локальном компьютере это localhost
     $user = 'mysql'; //имя пользователя, по умолчанию это root
     $password = 'mysql'; //пароль, по умолчанию пустой
     $db_name = 'tostelevision'; //имя базы данных
     $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db_name);
     // if ($link == false){
     // print("Ошибка: Невозможно подключиться к MySQL " . mysqli_connect_error());
     // }
     // else {
     // print("Соединение установлено успешно");
     // }

     $query = "SELECT headers, date_time, text_news1, image1 FROM news";
     $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
   ?>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <h3 class='mb-5'>Наши статьи</h3>
    <div class="container mt-5">
     <?php
     do {
      echo "<div class='red'>Вызывается новость</div>";
      echo $row['headers'];
      echo $row['date'];
      echo $row['text_news1'];
      echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image1']).'" class="img-thumbnail"/>';
     }
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     ?>`
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очевидно, что `$row` определяется __после__ первого выполнения блока `do`.

Comment: так окей, это я понял, а как тогда лучше написать?
upd; понял ошибку изменил цикл на просто `while` Спасибо!

Comment: не надо учить пхп по эти видеоукрсам. это очень плохой курс. Лучше купить хорошую книжку